# When setting up Amplify project (through amplify init), why does editor matter at all?

Tags: aws-amplify

When I init my project, it asks for:

1. project name
2. environment name
3. default editor
   ...

Why does Amplify setup process even care about my editor? (e.g., what it can do about it? does it change anything based upon different editor?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you `amplify api add` you have options to edit the default `schema.graphql` in the editor you pick.